# I'd like to hear thoughts about using time-series databases for this project:

Tags: database, time-series, influxdb, opentsdb, timescaledb

The project is to collect longitudinal data on inmates in a state prison system with the goals of recognizing time-based patterns and empowering prison justice advocates. The question is what time-series DB should I use?

**My starting point is this article:**

https://medium.com/schkn/4-best-time-series-databases-to-watch-in-2019-ef1e89a72377
and it's looking like the first 3 (InfluxDB, TimescaleDB, OpenTSDB) are on the table, but not so much the last one (I'm dealing with much more than strictly numerical data)

**Project details:**

Currently I'm using Postgres and plan to update the schema to look like (in broad strokes):

- low-volatility fields like: id number, name, race, gender, date-of-birth
- higher-volatility fields like: current facility, release date, parole eligibility date, etc
- time-series admin data: begin current, end current, period checked. Where this shows the time period the above 2 data fields are current and how often they were checked for changes.

I'm thinking it would be better to move to a time-series db and keep track of each individual update instead of having some descriptive info associated with a start date, end date, and period checked field. (like valid 2020-01-01 to 2021-08-25, checked every 14 days)

What I want to prioritize is speed of pulling reports (like what percentage of inmates grouped by certain demographics have exited the system before serving 90% of their sentence?) over insert throughput and storage space. I'm also interested in hearing opinions on ease of learning, prominence in the industry, etc.

**My background:**

I'm a bootcamp-educated generalist in data science with a background in CS. I've worked with SQL (Postgres, SQLite) and NoSQL (Mongo) databases in the past, and my DB-modeling ability is from an undergrad databases class. I'm most familiar with Java and Python (and many of the data science python packages), but learning a new language isn't a huge hurdle.

Thanks for your time!